# Install RAID0 on 2 GPT SSDs , booting in Legacy Mode, Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop

Tags: boot, grub2, raid

**My setup**

- 2x 512GB SSDs - GPT Partition
- Legacy boot

**ssd layout(on each disk):**

- 4MB: space reserved for bios grub(not part of RAID0 array)
- 16GB: swap - reserved for RAID volume
- 25GB : mnt / - ext4 - reserved for RAID volume
- ~420GB: mnt /home - ext4 - reserved for RAID volume

The error I eventually receive is **"executing 'grub-install /dev/md1 failed**"

I continued installation without bootloader thinking I will install grub by live-usb.

From the live-usb,

I ran `sudo grub-install /dev/nvme01n1`(name of ssd).
The error I receive is - **grub-install failed to get canonical path of aufs**'.

I tried `mount /dev/nvme01n1p3 /mnt` (the / of the RAID array), the error I receive is **unknown file-system linux_raid_member**'

mdadm does not detect any RAID disks ..

(I am following parts of the [Software RAID](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html) tutorial.
I plan to install desktop-ubuntu from within the server after installation, as shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwRrzE2ExX4))

**Other routes that I tried:**

- I tried adding the bios_grub reserved space to the RAID array but that resulted in an error during the formatting step.
- The disks initially had a msdos partition but I got the same bootloader error and I could not figure out how to allocate space for grub in msdos disks.
  After reading online, it seemed like booting from a GPT disk could be a solution and I changed the partition to GPT ..

This is taking especially long as I have started reading about MBR/GPT, BIOS/UEFI only when I began this install ..

Please let me know how I should proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran Boot repair from within the live-usb and it prompted me to remove dmraid as it would conflict with mdraid.

On doing so, I was able to run `mdraid --assemble --scan` and view my RAID0 disks.

Boot-repair eventually detected GPT partition and asked me to make a bios_grub, unformatted partition at beginning of disk. I was not sure how to proceed now as I already had the necessary partitions.

I then followed [this](http://sudo%20apt-get%20install%20python-rosinstall%20python-rosinstall-generator%20python-wstool%20build-essential) section of Grub2 installation. 
Grub was installed and I could login at tty1.